# Remove label text from grid on chart using morris.js

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, morris.js

I'm using [morris.js library](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) to generate charts.

I want to remove the labels from the chart. Please check the picture below for better understanding. How can I remove them?

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [{
      year: '2008',
      value: 20
    },
    {
      year: '2009',
      value: 10
    },
    {
      year: '2010',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      year: '2011',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      year: '2012',
      value: 20
    }
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value']
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable drawing along the x and y axes, set the `axes` option to `false`:

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  // Disable drawing the x and y axes
  axes: false
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

To have the x and y axes there (e.g. **for parsing purposes**), but make them invisible to the user, set the `gridTextSize` option to `0`:

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  // Make the x and y axes present, but small enough the user won't see it
  gridTextSize: 0
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

[**More on Morris.js Line Chart options**](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)